# What is the difference between the Legenday Super Saiyan form and the normal Super Saiyan form?

Tags: dragon-ball, dragon-ball-z

As we see from Broly's appearances, his LSSJ form seems much stronger than the normal SSJ's that we see him fight, but that is where the confusion begins. Just how much stronger is his form from the standard?

We see from games that his LSSJ form can ascend further, like the normal SSJ, into forms such as the Golden (or Green?) Oozaru, or the Super Saiyan 3. And the rumor of his Ki/power level constantly growing?

What are the exact distinctions that make the Legendary Super Saiyan unique?

Comment: Several saiyans have exhibited the ability to boost their power levels through the course of a fight. The most commonly seen example of this that I can think of is young Gohan rage boosting his power up far beyond what it was usually. Broly is not unique in that ability, though his berserker state may make rage boosting easier and more powerful.

Answer (score 2):

From the movies, its implied that Broly is so much more powerful as a supersayian because he is so much more powerful before going supersayian. He was born with a power level of 10,000 something goku does not achieve until after his training on king kai's planet (somewhere around age 30). It is also mentioned that Broly is essentially a biological anomaly that happens ever 1000 years to the sayains, in which he is essentially geneticly perfect and has increased strength, and easy access to his supersayian abilities. Piccolo mentions that now that vegeta is a super sayian his power probably surpasses goku since vegeta was the stronger non-super sayian. It also appears that brolys legendary form, seems to be a powerup similar to goku's ss3, in terms of how much he outclasses normal ss's.

Answer (score 0):

We have 2 Legendary Super Saiyans now, Broly and Kale. Both do the same things, tho Kale does reach Legendary Super Saiyan 2.

Super Saiyan = blonde hair, power level x 50 of your current level, must maintain anger to keep the form

Legendary Super Saiyan = green hair, power level x 50? x madness, lose self control and grow based on how berserk they get.

Legendary doesn't seem to have a cap on power-like the Hulk from Marvel, it just gets stronger, but at the cost of your self. It can be overpowered, but has to be hit in 1 shot. Legendary 2 seems to grant a multiple of the current level of the legendary super saiyan X an unknown amount, and preserves the Saiyan's mind.

In the movies, Broly consistently powers up beyond his current opponent. The opponent has to draw that power out of him however. Vegito was far beyond Broly during their fight, but Broly kept getting stronger slowly catching up. Vegito had to overwhelm him to bring him to defeat. Similiarly Kale-slowly grew in power, before getting knocked out by Jiren(who was well beyond anything she had hoped to reach)

The other Saiyans, use the additional transformations to reach higher or better levels of power. Legendary is just get mad get strong

Comment: the Hulk doesn't have a cap on power either...